# Securely allow access to a secure area of a website with PHP

Tags: php, web-development, websites, server-side

I am making a website that requires a secure area for the website owner to easily upload new content to. Because this is a relatively simple website there is no account system. I just have a URL for them to go to and enter a password (in a form with a ReCaptcha) to enter the secure area. My issue is, how do I allow access only after they are verified. Here are the options I've considered:

1. Set a session before I redirect the user from the verification `.php` the file where they are sent by the form. Then check for the session every time that page loads.
2. Name the secure area file something completely random so that it cannot be guessed. This would NOT be very secure so I would not want to do this.
3. Use the verification `.php` file as the secure area (Not ideal, but it's by far the most secure way I can think of)

Are there any options that I am missing? I couldn't find anything related to this at all online. This site doesn't have to be super secure, but I really don't want the wrong person getting in. I'm also asking this question for best practices later on.

Comment: Could you explain why you downvoted my question? If there is something you think needs changed, please tell me so I can.

Comment: I wasn't one of the downvotes, but this question strikes me as "teach me everything you know about securing a PHP website.  From the [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):   "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks, anyway suggestions on how I could make is reasonably scoped, or is it just how my question is?

Comment: State your objectives.  What are the deciding factors in making your choice?  ("Best practices" is not a deciding factor)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you *do* have an account system, only a very limited one that supports only a single authenticated account.

To prevent non-authenticated access to the admin pages, you should use the same mechanisms as what gets used by a more sophisticated account system for protecting pages that should be accessible only to authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a session. Sessions are a bit outdated and somewhat frowned upon because they may not scale well, but your use case does not need to scale.

In essence, most authentication schemes (with the exception of basic authentication that requires you to send username/password with each request) consists of a login step where some kind of token is generated when the client presents correct credentials and a logged-in phase where requests are considered authenticated when they contain this token. Whether you use session tokens or `Authentication` header contents is irrelevant for a simple single server app. For multiple server scenarios, you'd want to avoid sessions as they imply state that would need to be shared between service instances.